# How Can I Prepopulate The Entitlement Field Base On Case Record Type?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

When a user selects a particular Case record type in Salesforce, how can I prepopulate the Entitlement field?

I don't think that an Apex trigger would work. How can I override the Next button (Where the user selects the record type) click event or add to it?

How do I know what the existing code looks like for the Next button?

I am a newbie to Salesforce development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I'm not sure about editing the 'continue' buttons code on the recordType page but one option could be to create your own custom record type selection visualforce page and override the new case button to redirect to it. Then pass the entitlement field value (and the selected recordType) to the standard new case page via the url. Hope that helps a bit

Comment: If could pass the value via url, how would the standard new case page know what to do with it?

Comment: Sorry for late reply but you can pre-populate custom fields on standard new object pages with Url parameters where the parameters key is the ID of the custom field and the value is, of course, the value you want to populate the field with. [Here is a tutorial on how to do this](http://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-url-hacking-tutorial/)

Comment: The standard new case page automatically retrieves these parameters from the URL and sets the field's value using the id.